# Read a variable with AngularJs from Json?

Tags: html, angularjs, json

**I want to read the "title" of *submissions* with AngularJs. How do it ?**

```
[
    {
      "conference": "International Web Comics",
      "acronym": "IWCC 2016",
      "chairs": [
        "Jessica Jones <jessica.jones@alias.com>", 
        "Vanessa Ives <vanessa.ives@hell.com>",


       ],
      "submissions": [
        {
            "title": "The Microsoft Academic Research -- SAVE-S Keynote Talk",
            "authors": [
                "Ale <alee@example.com>"
            ],
            "url": "wade-savesd2016.html",
            "reviewers": [
                "Samanta  <sioni@un.it>",

            ]
```

Comment: Where is this Json? Is it actually a javascript object, or is it in a file? If it's in a file, is it on local disk (use FileReader() ) or a web resource (use $http)? Once you read it as a string you can use var obj = angular.fromJson()

Comment: It is a file.I try to make with this line code, but I don't receive the "title" with this 


<section class="row">
            <!-- Blog Sidebar Widgets Column -->
            <section class="col-md-4">
    var eventi = angular.module('eventsPopulate', [])
        eventi.controller('ctrlEventi', function($scope,$http) {
            $http.get("events.json")
            .success(function (response){
                $scope.arrayConferenze = response;
            });

Comment: Try using $scope.arrayConferenze = angular.fromJson(response) to turn it into an object, then you should be able to do arrayConferenze[0].submissions[0].title

Answer (score 1):

```
a=[ { "conference": "International Web Comics", "acronym": "IWCC 2016", "chairs": [ "Jessica Jones ", "Vanessa Ives ",

],
"submissions": [
{
    "title": "The Microsoft Academic Research -- SAVE-S Keynote Talk",
    "authors": [
        "Ale <alee@example.com>"
    ],
    "url": "wade-savesd2016.html",
    "reviewers": [
        "Samanta  <sioni@un.it>",

    ]
}]
}]

submission_title = a[0].submissions[0].title  //accessing submission title
```

Comment: I can't modify a json file. How can I do it ?

Comment: i didn't understand what you are trying to say, could you please describe your problem in detail.. :)

Comment: This is a file jason that I have in my folder. With my class I'will try to take only the "title " in my app.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with angularJS in specific. You just need to parse the javascript object (JSON) using dot (.) operator.

You can access objects property directly using . (dot) operator, if property is array then you need to access array by its index.

like in your case

```
var obj = [ { "conference": "International Web Comics", "acronym": "IWCC 2016", "chairs": [ "Jessica Jones ", "Vanessa Ives ",

   ],
  "submissions": [
    {
        "title": "The Microsoft Academic Research -- SAVE-S Keynote Talk",
        "authors": [
            "Ale <alee@example.com>"
        ],
        "url": "wade-savesd2016.html",
        "reviewers": [
            "Samanta  <sioni@un.it>",

        ]
```

You can access conference directly as

`obj.conference`

but for accessing submissions title you need to use

`obj.submissions[0].title`.